# Why is a video card needed to put my system in sleep mode?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, sleep

I'm using Windows 7 and some time ago my video card broke down. I can use the computer as I did, except I can't watch movies or play games, but that's okay with me. I'm not interested in putting any more money into it.

The only thing that bothers me is that now (with the video card disabled) I can't put my machine into sleep mode. Is there a way to go into sleep mode without a video card in Windows? Is it possible on Ubuntu (I might switch if that's the case)? Why is it required in the first place?

Comment: Technically a video card is not required at all. However is is quite possible that windows makes a few assumptions which fail when the device is disabled. Can you boot the computer *without* the card (not just disabled, with the card removed) and see if you can put it in sleep mode?

Comment: @Hennes The card is onboard, so no.

Comment: How do you know the card broke down? Also, how exactly are you using your computer when the on-board video is disabled? Finally, some details about your computer (desktop/laptop, brand, motherboard, CPU, etc.) would be helpful.

Comment: @Indrek see this question I asked: http://superuser.com/questions/398532/screen-is-black-at-login-screen-if-display-driver-is-enabled

Comment: So when you say you disabled the video card, you actually mean you uninstalled the Intel/Lenovo drivers and are now running with Windows' default drivers (low resolution, no hardware acceleration etc.)? What exactly happens when you try to put the laptop to sleep? Try checking the Event Viewer. Also go to System (Win+Pause) -> Performance Information and Tools (lower left corner) -> Advanced Tools (left side), and see if there are any warnings there about programs or drivers interfering with sleep mode.

Comment: @Indrek the sleep option is disabled (in the shutdown menu).

Comment: What if you press Fn+F4 (that should trigger sleep on your ThinkPad)?

Comment: Doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you connecting to it via RDP?

Comment: Connecting what to what?

Answer (score 0):

You can force hibernation from the keyboard, sleep mode ought to be possible as well.

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type in `shutdown -h -f` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  ( requires hibernation enabled and any Windows Client... perhaps not server OS

Try this command line or batch file:

```
%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe PowrProf.dll, SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

Comment: I get "The request is not supported.(50)".

Comment: spaces between switches ?? >  shutdown  -h  -f    also You must enable hibernation in order to use the -h option.

Answer (score 0):

I think my girlfriend had the exactly same issue on her HP Pavilion dv7, we still don't know if her graphics cards is dead or not, but we gave up on finding drivers and just wanted the sleep mode back...

on this site:
https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/force-sleep-with-programs-running.1946715/
I found this interesting command to run on cmd "powercfg.exe /energy" that makes one log file on the system32 folder that tells me that the video driver isn't responding to the sleep command and windows decided to disable it...

Then she came with the simple and genius idea of just disabling it on the device manager and BAM, after rebooting the sleep mode is working perfectly fine !

[PRINT OF THE DEVICE MANAGER OPTION (sorry to put this on portuguese)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXYRQ.png)